# Where are parameter values coming from?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a page with some imports and a class the renders the HTML:

```
import PageTen from '../layout/PageTen';

class MyAmazingClass extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const {
            someVariable,
            someOtherVariable
        } = this.props;
   
    return(<blahblah></blahblah>)
```

This is a pre-existing project and my knowledge of React is near zero - what I can't figure out from searching the project is where these `const` values are coming from. I looked for MyAmazingClass but can't see any references to it where this signature comes in to play.

I know they're populated because depending on the current user the values are different. I just don't know how they're populated.

Really beginner question but can someone point me in the right direction?!

Comment: How is this: `MyAmazingClass` called? This is where props are being passed. There are 2 ways, either its a direct passing like `<MyAmazingClass someVariable={...} />` or using `mapStateToProps` function

Comment: maybe you have `redux` and `mapStateToProps`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `props` are set in the declaration of your component.

Let me show an example from [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html):

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
```

and it can be called like this:

```
<Welcome name="Sara" />;
```